# kwallet + gpg kubntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gnupg, kwallet

I've installed **kubuntu 16.04** and create gpg key. But when I try to create a new wallet with **`kwallet`** it can't find no one encryption key. I tried to create pair of keys with **`gpg`** and **`kgpg`**, in both cases those keys used algorithms, that support encryption.

What shall I do to install the generated encryption key?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an imported key and solved by adding a trust to the key, the Kwallet service was able to find it. Probably when I imported it i didn't imparted any trust (I must say new keys created with Kgpg were working for me though)

In order to do that i fellow this guide
https://yanhan.github.io/posts/2014-03-04-gpg-how-to-trust-imported-key/

P.S. I answered this question even though i had the issue with kubuntu 19.10, but I believe the problem is the same.

Comment: Your link appears to be dead as of 2021-03-10. It would help if you could place the steps in your answer.